# CSS code formatting and styling with Sublime

Tags: css, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, csstidy

I'd like to convert my CSS in the following format:

```
selector,selector,selector { property: value; property: value;... }
selector { property: value; }
```

All of the plugins either need PHP / NodeJS or JAVA installed (I am using a VM for my server stuff, only the editor is on my host machine which I prefer to keep light-weight).

Comment: Have you tried *[Minify](https://github.com/tssajo/Minify)* package? It is supposed to work with ST2 and ST3. Also well-known *[Minifier](https://github.com/bistory/Sublime-Minifier)* package would do the trick.

Comment: @HashemQolami I don't want to create minified version on save, I was looking for a plugin that will actually change the code source while I am working on it - I'm not doing all this for minification but for my own preference, I like 1-line CSS declarations as they give me a good overview of my code.

Comment: Downvoters: Please explain the downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying almost all available packages for Sublime that do CSS formatting, and the one that worked out of the box was CSS Format https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CSS%20Format . Works excellent, no external dependencies.